# Avoid black screen between activities without using AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I would like to avoid or customize these black transitions between activities, they are annoying.

I've read that the solution is using AsyncTask but I would like to know if there is another way of doing the same.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using
    android:launchMode="singleInstance"
by any chance? My activities were light as a feather, but I was experiencing a 200ms delay using singleInstance. Changing to standard resolved the issue.

Comment: I'm not using singleInstance. I think the delay was due to the load of some big images at the same time in the activity. Thank's for you comment.

Comment: I'm experiencing a black screen between activities that are marked as "singleInstance". Is there a reason for this, and any workaround?

Comment: @Michael Herbig: No reason I'm aware of except that all docs strongly urge developers not to use it. My guess is that it remains untested and unsupported. The only workaround is not to use it. I later saw that none of my activities actually needed it.

Answer (score 0):

1- using the progress bar in onCreate and do bulky operation then handler.postDelayed or in Async task......

2- 
I think inserting the animation while activity transaction is also a option using overridePendingTransition......... but have doubt it may increase the waiting time :(

http://blog.blundell-apps.com/animate-an-activity/

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/Animation.html

http://www.warriorpoint.com/blog/2009/05/26/android-switching-screens-in-an-activity-with-animations-using-viewflipper/

http://chrisrisner.com/31-Days-of-Android--Day-17%E2%80%93Animating-between-Activities

Comment: With your solution I can change the activity transition but when I kill a process and the activity die the black screen continue when I return to the back activity.

Comment: I think you are talkinmg about when you comes B-> a back pressering back key right ? the override the an onKeyDown(int i, KeyEvent event) as in http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=343 "Yet another example"